# Private inheritance and returning references from functions

Tags: c++, private-inheritance

Now I have code below:

```
class Env
{
public:
   int ra(){ return a;}
   int rb(){ return b;}
private:
   int a;
   int b;
};


class CEnv: private Env
{
public:
    static Env* Instance()
    {
        CEnv* pEnv = new CEnv;
        return pEnv;
    }

};



int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    Env* pEnv = CEnv::Instance();
    pEnv->ra();

    return 0;
}
```

And it works well.Later I add some code.

```
class Env
{
public:
   int ra(){ return a;}
   int rb(){ return b;}
private:
   int a;
   int b;
};


class CEnv: private Env
{
public:
    static Env* Instance()
    {
        CEnv* pEnv = new CEnv;
        return pEnv;
    }

};

Env* test()
{
    CEnv *p = new CEnv;
    return p;
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    Env* pEnv = CEnv::Instance();
    pEnv->ra();

    return 0;
}
```

Then VS2010 will tell out compiler error :
error C2243: 'type cast' : conversion from 'CEnv *' to 'Env &' exists, but is inaccessible.

In my opinion, it's right to show the error ,because it's not  as-a relationship if using private herit.
But the first code pattern works well.
And I wonder why ?

Comment: "_And it works well_" No it doesn't.

Comment: In my vs2010, it works well indeed. And which error shows in your computer ?

Comment: *Where* do you get the error? On what line? Can you please mark it out with a comment? I don't even see anywhere you use use pointers to `CEnv`.

Comment: I use no pointer but the quote.The error occures in                           Env& test()
{
    static CEnv env;
    return env; //compiler error here
}

Comment: `static Env& Instance() { CEnv env; return env; }` - you can't return a reference to an automatic stack-hosted variable and expect it to work reliably.  That's undefined behaviour, and will be covered in any introductory C++ book.  Hundreds of existing SO Q&A discuss this: search for *"C++ return reference to local variable"*.  Note that making the function `static` does ***not*** make the variable `static`.

Comment: By definition, private inheritance isn't accessible to other functions, just like private members.

Comment: Thansk for your suggestion and now i fixed code errors.And my question is why the second code pattern have errors ? @ Tony D

Comment: @xin Read [ask]. This is not a discussion forum. You can't post follow-up questions in an existing question, let alone the comments on an existing question...

Comment: I can not @ somebody ,so i just write my comment below, so don't mind, and thanks for all of your answers. When curisousguy say "By definition, private inheritance isn't accessible to other functions, just like private members", I agree with it, but why the first code pattern works and no error. I think it is conflict.

Comment: You shouldn't remove the original code from your question - now nobody knows what you were asking or why existing comments and answers discuss the mistakes you had made.

Comment: OK, i am so sorry , and i will learn "how to ask" ,and will not make this mistake, thakns.

Comment: @TonyD Comments have a time and edit history is accessible, but perhaps after a significant edit one should post a big comment warning "_________ question edited NOW _________"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you replace private inheritance with a private member you will get the exact same result:

```
class Env
{ /* whatever */
};

class CEnv{
private: 
    Env m;

public:
    static Env *Instance()
    {
        CEnv *pEnv = new CEnv; /* memory leak */
        return &pEnv->m;
    }
};
```

(Forget about the memory leak as this is just for illustrative purpose.)

Here the member is accessible **because `Instance()` is a member of the class**.

With a non-member function:

```
Env *test()
{
    CEnv *p = new CEnv;
    return &p->m;
}
```

Function `test()` isn't a member or friend; [try it](https://ideone.com/KpMm4R) :

```
prog.cpp: In function 'Env* test()':
prog.cpp:7:13: error: 'Env CEnv::m' is private
         Env m;
             ^
prog.cpp:20:20: error: within this context
         return &p->m;
                    ^
```

Make it a friend if you must:

```
class CEnv2 {
private: 
    Env m;
    friend Env *::test2();
};

Env *test2()
{
    CEnv2 *p = new CEnv2;
    return &p->m;
}
```

Now [it compiles](https://ideone.com/7prfdo).

Answer (score 0):

Your `Instance()` method is broken, you should only have 1 `static` object:

```
static Env* Instance()
{
    static CEnv instance;
    return &instance;
}
```

Or, reference case:

```
static Env& Instance()
{
    static CEnv instance;
    return instance;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and i fixed my code just now. And now i wonder why private inheritance could access functions of parent class. In 2rd code pattern ,it is not allowed in test() function ,so i think it is right, but in Instance() function , it works.

Comment: Because the derived constructor always has access to the base class' constructor.

Comment: @JameyD "the derived constructor always has access to the base class' constructor" hug?

Comment: I'm sorry ,i still confused.There is no explicit constructor but default constructor. Instance() function is just an ordinary function. So i still don't understand.Could you explain it more clearly?

Comment: @xingfu0539 No, `Instance()` is a member function.

Answer (score 0):

Private inheritance is an "is-a" relationship that is a secret to everyone except the inheriting class itself.

Inside your `CEnv` class, the inheritance is "known" (private inheritance would be mostly useless if the inheriting class weren't allowed to know about it).

Thus, the conversion from `CEnv*` to `Env*` in `CEnv::Instance` is valid, since it's `CEnv` that does the conversion.

The `test` function is not a member of `CEnv`, so from its point of view the conversion isn't allowed.